# Delphi Android getConfiguredNetworks

Tags: android, delphi

I am trying to get the List of Saved Networks , and only delete the one with Specific SSID .
This is what I did till now :

```
procedure TMainScreen.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var obj: JObject;
    WifiMgr : JWifiManager;

    Networks : JList;
    i : integer;
begin
  obj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE);
  WifiMgr := TJwifiManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

  Networks :=  WifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks;

  for i := 0 to Networks.size-1 do
  begin


  end;

  Toast('Configured Networks : '+inttostr(Networks.size),TToastLength.ShortToast);

end;
```

This gets the List of Networks, but I have no idea how can I access say Configuration 1 SSID .

I found following example on Stackoverflow . But I am having a hard time understanding/converting it .

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               

         break;
    }           
 }
```

Please help.
Regards
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it like this :

```
procedure TMainScreen.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var obj: JObject;
    WifiMgr : JWifiManager;

    Networks : JList;
    Config : JWifiConfiguration;
    i : integer;
begin
  obj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE);
  WifiMgr := TJwifiManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

  Networks := WifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks;

  for i := 0 to Networks.size-1 do
  begin
    Config := TJWifiConfiguration.Wrap((Networks.get(i) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

    if JStringToString(Config.SSID) = '"robert-net2"' then
    begin
      Toast('Network ID '+inttostr(Config.networkId), TToastLength.ShortToast);
      WifiMgr.removeNetwork(Config.networkId);
    end;

  end;

end;
```